# How is it possible to represent linear combination by augmented matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

That's from an exercise in Hoffman and Kunze Linear Algebra book.

Let be the vectors $\alpha_1=(1,0,i)$ and $\alpha_2=(1+i,1,-1)$. Also, let $\beta_1=(1,1,0)$ and $\beta_2=(1,i,1+i)$. Show that $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ can be written as linear combinations of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

By row-reducing the augmented matrix

$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 1+i & 1 & 1 \\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & i \\\ 
i & -1 & 0 & 1+i
\end{array}\right]
$

We get

$
\left[\begin{array}{rr|rr}
1 & 0 & -i & 2-i \\\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & i \\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$

Then by this result, we take the coefficients from the resulting matrix, so that

$\beta_1=-i\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ and $\beta_2=(2-i)\alpha_1+i\alpha_2$

What I can't understand is how it's possible to represent linear combinations by an augmented matrix in such a way, and get the coefficients by that row-reduced matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding linear combinations simply means: we want $c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2 \in\mathbb{C}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\alpha_1c_1+\alpha_2c_2&=\beta_1\\
\alpha_1d_1+\alpha_2d_2&=\beta_2\\
\end{align*}
Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}\uparrow & \uparrow \\\alpha_1 & \alpha_2\\ \downarrow & \downarrow\end{bmatrix}$. Then these equations can be written as
$$A\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}=\beta_1 \quad \text{ and } \quad A\begin{bmatrix}d_1\\d_2\end{bmatrix}=\beta_2.$$
For each system, we can use the augmeneted matrix $[A | \beta_i]$ to solve for the coefficients. However, we can solve both of them together (as the row operations will be the same) by using the combined augmeneted matrix $[A \, | \, \beta_1 \,\, \beta_2]$.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a well-written answer and clarification. The power of matrices amazes me.